# Examples of completely integrable system

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry

Let $X$ be a Fano manifold (different from $\mathbb{P}^n$) of dimension $n$ and Picard rank one. If its cotangent bundle $T^*X$ admits $n$ independent Poisson commuting regular functions then $T^*X$ is a completely integrable system with the moment map $T^*X \to \mathbb{C}^n$ defined by these functions. For example, if $X$ is the moduli space of vector bundles on curves, then $T^*X$ is completely integrable system.

Question: Is there any other example of such $X$, different from the moduli space of vector bundles ?

Comment: No. I want $X$ such that  its  cotangent bundle is integrable system.

Comment: Right, I misread your question.

Comment: The homogeneous spaces $G/P$ are also examples of such Fano. I am looking for an example which is different from these two examples.

Comment: How about specializations of $G/P$ as in the article of Pasquier-Perrin?

Comment: In a post in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/210100/specialisation-of-rigid-varieties , there is  an example where the specialization of a projective homogeneous space is not homogeneous.  Does the example works for my question also? i.e., its cotangent bundle is integrable system ?

Comment: I guess I am wrong. $T^*(G/P)$ is not completely integrable system, as the fiber of the moment map is not of dimension $\frac{1}{2} \text{dim}(T^*(G/P))$.